# Why does the shader program fail to compile despite linking and validating successfully?

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, shader, jogl

Shader program does not link despite the vertex and fragment shaders compiling successfuly. No error message is retreived using `glGetProgramInfoLog()`. A value of `GL_FALSE` is, however, retreived within the `success` buffer variable (the `GLException` is thrown with an empty message). Here is the code:

```
private int compileProgram(String[] vertexShaderSource, String[] fragmentShaderSource) 
        throws GLException {
    // compiling vertex and fragment shaders from source

    int vertexShader = compileShader(GL4.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderSource); // OK
    int fragmentShader = compileShader(GL4.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderSource); // OK
    int id = gl.glCreateProgram(); // OK

    // attaching the shaders to the shader program and linking it

    gl.glAttachShader(id, vertexShader);
    gl.glAttachShader(id, fragmentShader);
    gl.glLinkProgram(id);
    gl.glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    gl.glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    IntBuffer success = IntBuffer.allocate(1);

    gl.glGetProgramiv(id, GL4.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, success);    // GL_FALSE

    // checking for errors

    if (success.get(0) == GL4.GL_FALSE) {
        IntBuffer infoLogLength = IntBuffer.allocate(1);

        gl.glGetProgramiv(id, GL4.GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, infoLogLength);

        ByteBuffer infoLog = ByteBuffer.allocate(infoLogLength.get(0));

        gl.glGetProgramInfoLog(id, infoLogLength.get(0), infoLogLength, infoLog);

        // Empty error message           

        String errorMessage = new String(infoLog.array(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

        throw new GLException(errorMessage);
    }

     return id;
}
```

Here is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vypxmer0nhssbs2/shader.txt?dl=0) to the file containing the two shaders (in the program, each shader is actually contained within its own `String[]` variable).

**P.S.:** I have the same code structure in C++ and it works flawlessly.

Comment: Yes and I have even tested it. If I add a mistake in any of the shaders, it will return me the error (_e.g._ `ERROR: 0:6: 'sf' : syntax error syntax error`). But now I have no error from them.

Comment: `success.get(0) != GL4.GL_TRUE` Never test against `GL_TRUE`. Always test against `GL_FALSE`.

Comment: @NicolBolas Alright, now testing against `GL_FALSE`. That did not change anything (also, using the debugger I could see before that `success.get(0)` returned 0).

Comment: Looking at my old shader code; you could try using `glValidateProgram(id)` after `glLinkProgram(id)` and checking `glGetProgrami(id, GL_LINK_STATUS)` and `glGetProgrami(id, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS)` as well.

Comment: @JornVernee, thanks, will try this

Comment: @JornVernee The results are: linked successfully, validated successfully, failed to compile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> gl.glGetProgramiv(id, GL4.GL_COMPILE_STATUS, success);    // GL_FALSE
> ```

*Program object* do not have a compile status, only shaders do. Trying to query `GL_COMPILE_STATUS` on a program object will only result in a `GL_INVALID_ENUM` value, and the content of your `success` value will not be modified in any way.

Comment: You are right, but I am surprised JOGL didn't throw `GLException` with `GL_INVALID_ENUM` message. Oh well.